# Save multiple linear regression models

Tags: r, model

I simulated some data and I want to loop the simulation 1000 times. I need to fit the data to a linear model each time and save all the information.

One of my friend told me I can extract the coefficients of standard errors each time and save them to make them a matrix or data frame. However, I want to know if I can save a model. I want to simulate 1000 times and save all the models.

but how do i analyze overall model from the 1000 times?
like if the model fit well, i want to use summary(model)
and see if each variable significant and if the f statistic is significant or not?

Answer (score 2):

You can store all your models as a list and then write them to a file with the `save` function:

```
lst <- lapply(1:1000, function(repetition) {
  mod <- lm(...)  # Replace this with the code you need to train your model
  return(mod)
})
save(lst, file="myfile.RData")
```

Later, you could load the data again with `load("myfile.Rdata")`, and then access them with `lst[[1]]`, `lst[[2]]`, ...

Comment: thanks for your input.
but how do i analyze overall model?
like if the model fit well, i want to use summary(model)
and see if each variable significant

Comment: @Hsiang-WeiWu if you liked the 10th model, you would run `summary(lst[[10]])`. If you wanted to output summary information for all 1000 models, you would run `lapply(lst, summary)`.

Comment: thanks! i'll try now, does the output give overall like as one model?or it gives every coefficients in 1000 models?

Comment: @Hsiang-WeiWu `lst[[10]]` is an actual model. As usual, you could get the coefficients of the model with `coef(lst[[10]])`.